# Strapi CMS get next or previous entry

Tags: rest, content-management-system, strapi

i've created CMS with Strapi /MongoDB and REST/.

Is there any way to get next content. I want to display next content details on specific content page.
Or should i customize `id` field to `auto increment` field and get content using add one to `id` field.
Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After few tries, I've decided to make `id` field to `auto increment` and sent request by adding or subtracting one from `id`. There were no other solution. If `id` is one its first content or if the next contents' response is 404 its the last content. This is how i solved this problem. If you have simpler or better solution let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is simpler or better neccessarily, but I added relations for previousArticle and nextArticle and manually assigned them.  It's more upkeep but more control.  To each their own

Comment: I would add another field `position` (integer), to manually control the order of entries (i.e. in a documentation). Then the `position` can be used to retrieve previous & next items.

Comment: Autoincrement can't work, because some entry can be deleted or unpublished and you dont get next or previous object.

Comment: As @VítZadina said, this doesn't work as soon as you delete entries or have unpublished content. This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For previous item you can call get all endpoint with filter with less than actual_ID. And sort it by id and go with size pages 1 and you get first item which is published and exist and is prev. Same for next but with filter with bigger than actual_ID.